# In the android application, image isn't showing after closing app and restarting it

Tags: android

In an app I am allowing user to pick image from gallery or he can choose from camera. Though I can manage the image and show it in the activity in the first time, after closing the app and restarting it, the image is gone and the space is blank.There was an explanation given to me to save the image data in sharedPreferences but I am new in android and don't pretty much understand. I looked for sharedPreferences but don't know how to make it work.
So if anybody help kindly with some explanation and code, it would help me a lot.
Thanks.
Here is what I tried to do.

```
    private void openCamera(){
        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName)); // set the image file name

        // If you call startActivityForResult() using an intent that no app           can handle, your app will crash.
        // So as long as the result is not null, it's safe to use the intent.
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Start the image capture intent to take photo
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_IMAGE);
            }
        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       // final android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageview.getLayoutParams();

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            imageview.setImageURI(imageUri);
            //selectedImagePath = getPath(imageUri);
            //ystem.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
        }

        else if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri takenPhotoUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
            // by this point we have the camera photo on disk
            Bitmap rawTakenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhotoUri.getPath());
            // RESIZE BITMAP, see section below
            // See BitmapScaler.java: https://gist.github.com/nesquena/3885707fd3773c09f1bb
            // Get height or width of screen at runtime
            int screenWidth = DeviceDimensionsHelper.getDisplayWidth(this);
// Resize a Bitmap maintaining aspect ratio based on screen width

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth(rawTakenImage,screenWidth);
            // Load the taken image into a preview
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Compress the image further
            resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
// Create a new file for the resized bitmap (`getPhotoFileUri` defined above)
            Uri resizedUri = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName + "_resized");
            File resizedFile = new File(resizedUri.getPath());

// Write the bytes of the bitmap to file
            try{
                resizedFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resizedFile);
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fos.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error occured");
            }


            imageview.setImageBitmap(rawTakenImage);
        }

    }

        public Uri getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
        // Only continue if the SD Card is mounted
            if (isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
            // Get safe storage directory for photos
            // Use `getExternalFilesDir` on Context to access package-specific directories.
            // This way, we don't need to request external read/write runtime permissions.
                File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
            }

            // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
            return Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName));
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Returns true if external storage for photos is available
        private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            return state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        }
```

Comment: Image data is too big so don't save image data in `SharedPreference`, if you are learning. Save image base64 in database or save image path in database for view image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below ways to store image.

**1. Database with Base64**

- You can convert image into **base64 string** and **store** in **database**.
  So when you open application you can **retrieve** **base64** String from **database** and **display** image in `ImageView`.

**2. Store Image Path in Database**

- You can store image **path** in **database**, when you open application, just **retrieve** image **path** and **display** image in `ImageView`.
  But if you delete image from memory, you will not get image from iamge path.

**3. Store Image in Server.**

- If you **store** image in **server**, you can retrieve image path and **download** image using **`AsyncTask`** or sime 3rd party liberary. And display image in `ImageView`.
  (Liberaries : Picaso, LazyLoading etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't learnt Database yet. So I think I should start.

Comment: ya. You should. You will find anything from internet.

Comment: Is there any free SQL Server you can suggest kindly?